# How do I fade in a div by id if cookie=1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with few tabs.
I am looking for a way that if you select tab 5 and cookie = 1 then show tab6 otherwise show tab5.

The code for the tabs is:

```
jQuery(".tabs a").click(function () {
    stringref = jQuery(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];
    jQuery('.tab_content:not(#' + stringref + ')').hide();
    jQuery('.tab_content#' + stringref).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

I want the tab number 5, if clicked and cookie=1 to show tab6.
The code that shows the div5 or Div6 if cookie is 1 or null is:

```
alreadyClosed = $.cookie(stateCookieName);

if (alreadyClosed != 1) {
    $DIV5.show();
    $DIV6.hide();
} else {
    $DIV5.hide();
    $DIV6.show();
}
```

How do I add them together? I assume their should be a way to say:

```
If tab1.click and cookie = 1 then show $div1
else tab1.click and cookie = null then show $div2
```

The body looks like:

```
<!-- buttons -->
<ul id="boxes" class="tabs">
<li><a href="#Div5">Div 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#Div6">Div 6</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- content -->
<div class="tab_content" id="Div5">DIV 5</div>
<div class="tab_content" id="Div6">DIV 6</div>
```

I hope you guys can help me. 
Thanks alot & Regards,
rallyboy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so long I found it out finally. I replaced this click function with this:

```
var alreadyClosed = $.cookie(stateCookieName) == '1';
jQuery('ul.tabs a').click(function () {
    var ref = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    if (alreadyClosed && ref == 'Div5') {
        ref = 'Div6';
    }
    jQuery('div.tab_content:not(#' + ref + ')').hide();
    jQuery('#' + ref).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(".tabs a").click(function () {
    alreadyClosed = $.cookie(stateCookieName);

    stringref = jQuery(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];

    if(alreadyClosed == 1)
    {
        newstring = stringref;
        if(stringref == "5")
        {
            newstring = "6";
        }
        elseif(stringref == "6")
        {
            newstring = "5";
        }
        stringref = newstring;
    }

    jQuery('.tab_content:not(#' + stringref + ')').hide();
    jQuery('.tab_content#' + stringref).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

This extra code does a quick check - if the cookie is set, it toggles 5 to 6 or 6 to 5.  Then it proceeds as normal.

Do you need a more general solution than this for tabs 5 and 6?  If so, can you please lay out some rules for how exactly it should work?

Comment: Fantastic answer sir. I am working to solve this problem 3 days now. I've spent so many hours on it. Anyway, when the cookie is set to 1 it doesn't show the Tab6. All I want is to IF cookie = 1 and I click tab5 then show tab6, and if cookie = null and I click tab 5 it shows tab5 as it does now.

Comment: At the moment if there is no cookie it works perfectly but when I set the cookie it doesn't. Let me know if you want a quick Fiddle of the exact page. I guess the problem is with the number 5 and 6 you wrote on your code. I tried replacing with #Div5 and #Div6 or Div5 and Div6 but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'll have a look at this tomorrow and get it worked out for ya.  I'm sure it's pretty close.  Your fiddle will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me out. After so long I found it out finally. I replaced this click function with this:     var alreadyClosed = $.cookie(stateCookieName) == '1';
    jQuery('ul.tabs a').click(function() {
        var ref = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
        if (alreadyClosed && ref == 'Div5') {
            ref = 'Div6';
        }
        jQuery('div.tab_content:not(#' + ref + ')').hide();
        jQuery('#' + ref).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".tabs a").click(function () {
    stringref = jQuery(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];

    // Normal navigation
    if(stringref != 'div5') {
        jQuery('.tab_content:not(#' + stringref + ')').hide();
        jQuery('.tab_content#' + stringref).fadeIn();
    } else {
        // 5 is special, do further checking
        var alreadyClosed = $.cookie(stateCookieName);

        if (alreadyClosed != 1) {
            $('div5').show();
            $('div6').hide();
        } else {
            $('div5').hide();
            $('div6').show();
        }           
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. It seems that if I have the cookie or not it still shows the selected Tab. Please mentioned that each tab has class tab_content. I made a quick fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nsgcn/ on how it actually looks. Thanks alot again